# Creating an object for a hash key

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create an object for a hash key.  Here is my object.

```
def CompositeKey
  def initialize(name, id)
      @id=id
      @name=name
   end
end
```

and then later in the same file I am trying to use it.

```
def add_to_list(list, obj)
  # Find or create the payer
  key = CompositeKey.new(obj["PAYER NAME"], obj['PAYER ID'])
  payer = list[key]
  if payer.nil?
    payer = {}
    list[key] = payer
  end

  # Copy the values into the payer
  copy_to_payer(obj, payer)
end
```

but I keep getting an error. `rb:57:in 'add_to_list': uninitialized constant CompositeKey (NameError)`.
What am I missing?  How do I make this work?

Comment: How about using key.id as the hash key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change 'def' to 'class'

```
class CompositeKey
...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the class correctly and implement the `hash` and `eql?` methods or else it won't work as a hash key:

```
class CompositeKey

  include Comparable

  attr_reader :id, :name

  def initialize(name, id)
      @id=id
      @name=name
   end

   def hash
     name.hash
   end

   def <=>(other)
     result = self.id <=> other.id
     if result == 0
       self.name <=> other.name
     else
       result 
     end
   end

end
```

By including `Comparable` and implementing `<=>` you will have correct `eql?` and `==` implementations and your object should now be safe to use as a hash key.

Comment: Nice answer.  <=> can be simply `[self.id, self.name] <=> [other.id, other.name]`, or to deal with the minor DRY violation, create an method such as `state` that returns the array, then `self.state <=> other.state`.

Comment: Nice, didn't know that!

Answer (score 1):

If the only reason for the existence of the CompositeKey class is to be a hash key, you can do it more simply by using an array as the key:

```
 key = [obj["PAYER NAME"], obj['PAYER ID']]
```

This works because Arrays create their hash key out of the hash keys of their elements.